# cross compile OpenJDK jdk8u102-b14, zeroshark for ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, java

I have managed to cross compile OpenJDK jdk8u102-b14 `zeroshark` after applied patches, mostly from [here](https://github.com/rdm-dev/meta-java/blob/master/recipes-core/openjdk/patches-openjdk-8/openjdk8-fix-shark-build.patch). But when I run `java`, I see assert from `sharkCompiler.cpp:347` : `assert(code != NULL) failed: code must be != NULL`

LLVM I use is 3.4.2, cross compiled for ARM with library FFI, enable targets for ARM.

From debug message, it's because `generate_native_code` for `java.lang.String::equals` get `NULL` pointer at line `code = (address) execution_engine()->getPointerToFunction`

`java.lang.String::hashCode` and `java.lang.System::arraycopy` not problem.

What's the possible root cause for this failure? Why `java.lang.String::hashCode` OK while `equals` from same package failed?

```
[root@Z303XY84 ~]# /mnt/target/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk-image/bin/java
Target Triple = arm-unknown-linux-gnu              <<< debug message
compile_method: java.lang.String::hashCode
add_function : java.lang.String::hashCode
Function Name : java.lang.String::hashCode, OK
compile_method: java.lang.String::equals
add_function : java.lang.String::equals
Function Name : java.lang.String::equals, NULL     <<<<<<<<< Here is the problem
# To suppress the following error report, specify this argument
# after -XX: or in .hotspotrc:  SuppressErrorAt=/sharkCompiler.cpp:347
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (/output/build/openjdk-jdk8u102-b14/hotspot/src/share/vm/shark/sharkCompiler.cpp:347), pid=4204, tid=0x4d21f470
#  assert(code != NULL) failed: code must be != NULL
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-fastdebug-8u102-b14-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Shark VM (25.102-b14-fastdebug mixed mode linux-arm )
# Core dump written. Default location: /root/core or core.4204
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/hs_err_pid4204.log
generate_native_wrapper: java.lang.System::arraycopy
add_function : java.lang.System::arraycopy
Function Name : java.lang.System::arraycopy, OK
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
# [ timer expired, abort... ]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I would use the Oracle build which has already been tested. You could try an OpenJDK forum, but this is not a general Java programming question, so you might get an answer here only if you are lucky.

Comment: And just wondering, as it have many years since I last tried to bring a JVM to another platform: you are sure that you just need to cross-compile; and that there is nothing in there that requires code changes or such things?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, Oracle build works well on our platform. But we want to do a benchmark between OpenJDK zeroshark and Oracle SE on our platform.

Comment: @GhostCat No, I am not sure. I use patches from Debian armel build, and successfully build OpenJDK zero VM, and run on our platform without issue except it is too slow compare to Oracle version. On top of the zero, I want to build zeroshark to do another round of benchmark vs Oracle JDK.

Comment: I know this is old, but I would be interested in hearing an update.  I have tentative plans to attempt to build sharkzero, but I'm trying to get a clean, repeatable build for my port, which is mipsel with musl libc.  Personally, I don't presume that I won't have to debug and modify Shark to get it to work, especially since it's no longer being maintained -- this is a pity because the work to implement a JIT compiler is massive.  Also, I thought there was a native hotspot jit for arm.